# c# - Best way to bind multiple lists to multiple chart series

Tags: c#, winforms

I have several instances of a class containing a `BindingList`.  The list is updated periodically.

```
public class myclass
{
    public BindingList<double> values;
    public string name;
    //....code

    public void UpdateVaues()
    {
        //Get somevalue
        values.Add(somevalue);
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like to put several of these lists in something like a DataTable and just do:

```
chart1.DataSource = datatable;
```

And then later:

```
chart1.DataBind();
```

and have everything updated.

Currently I am just constantly rebinding each list one at a time:

```
//Inside main form
chart1.Series["one"].Points.DataBindY(myclass1.values);
chart1.Series["two"].Points.DataBindY(myclass2.values);
//...
```

I can't believe this is the best way.  Any ideas?

Comment: Within your UpdateVaues(), try calling your page loader to reload with new values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This isn't actually a web application but a win forms app.  Also `myclass` doesn't have access to the rest of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DataSet with DataTables and an ObservableCollection if you are looking for one source with multiple bindings.

```
public class myclass
{
    public DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    public DataTable dt1;
    public DataTable dt2;

    public ObservableCollection<double> values1;
    public ObservableCollection<double> values2;

    public myclass() {
        values1.CollectionChanged += values1Changed;
    }

    public void CreateTables()
    {
        // Create the DataSet

        // Create the Data Tables
        dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt2 = new DataTable();

        dataSet.Tables.Add(dt1);
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dt1);

        chart1.DataSource = dataSet;
    }

    private void values1Changed(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        //Get somevalue (what changed)
        dt1.Rows.Add(somevalue);

        chart1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Edit: Another possible solution based on `BindingSource` with multiple `BindingList`

```
    public BindingSource bindingSource { get; set; } = new BindingSource();
    public BindingList<BindingList<double>> bindingList { get; set; } = new BindingList<BindingList<double>>();
    public BindingList<double> values1 { get; set; } = new BindingList<double>();
    public BindingList<double> values2 { get; set; } = new BindingList<double>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bindingList.Add(values1);
        bindingList.Add(values2);

        bindingSource.DataSource = bindingList;

        chart1.DataSource = bindingSource;
    }
```

Disclaimer: I haven't fully tested this but you can see if it works. You will also need to set the DataMembers on the chart.

Comment: Thanks! this was really helpful and works great.  I'm still bothered that there isn't an easier way.  It seems there should be a structure that I could bind to/chart that can hold the list (not just take the values of the list).  For instance I can just set the data source of a `DataGridView` as  a binding list.  Then I just add the objects I want to the list.  Changes to the added objects (not just the binding list) are then reflected in the `DataGridView`.  Is there no equivalent for a chart data source?

Comment: Well, I added another possible solution, but I haven't fully tested it. You could use a BindingList of BindingList's with a BindingSource on the chart, and then set the DataMembers to the specific chart components. If the DataMember's need property names, you could create a class that derives from `BindingList<BindingList<double>` and add the BindingList's as properties on that object, and then set that object to a binding source. Like I said, I haven't fully tested it, but it might work.